# Changing Chromecast orientation from browser to monitor

Tags: google-chrome, casting, chromecast, landscape, portrait

I have a google sheet I need to cast to a separate monitor, but all the data must be displayed without scrolling so I need to have the sheet displayed in portrait mode.

I have to build the spreadsheet using Excel then paste it into a Google Sheet in order to cast it. Any idea how to cast to a monitor that is setup for portrait mode so that all the data will fit on one screen? Thanks so much for ANY advice!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to cast in a vertically mounted TV (Portrait), I think this is not possible as per [Chromecast Help Forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/YxU-DuMedco). It was also identified that [the rotation of the display using Chromecast](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/FCP8otkxSic) is not possible as it is a work that should be done by the settings of the mobile/PC device you are casting from. Also, to help you understand more, check the [overall design principles](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ux_guidelines#overall_design_principles).

Comment: You're awesome. I was on the line with tech support and I think I broke their brain with this question. Thank you!!!

Comment: If this answers your question, kindly give some love... :)

Comment: I tried like five times. I have less than 15 reputation so it records it but doesn't show it unless I have at least 15. I definitely upvoted it though!!!

Answer (score 0):

Wound up using Chromebits. It was a bit more expensive but the option to change the screen orientation is built in to the OS.